# Symfony 4: Event listener Cannot autowire UserInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

When I add UserInterface to my event listener, then I have following error:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\EventListener\ControllerListener": argument "$user" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface" but no such service exists. It cannot be auto-registered because it is from a different root namespace.
```

I don't know what is going on, other services working fine.
Can you look for code and tell me what am I doing wrong?

**~src/EventListener/ControllerListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\DailyWin;
use App\Controller\DailyWinController;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

class ControllerListener extends Controller implements DailyWinController
{
    private $authChecker, $user, $logger;

    public function __construct(UserInterface $user, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->authChecker = $authChecker;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event) {
        if ($this->authChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === false) return;

        $this->logger->warning('Inicjowanie...');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $DWrep = $em->getRepository(DailyWin::class);

        $userId = $this->user->getId();
        $userDailyWin = $DWrep->findOneBy(['userId' => $userId]);
        $this->logger->warning(print_r($userDailyWin));

        if (empty($userDailyWin)) {
            $currentDate = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d', time()));
            $userDailyWin = new DailyWin();
            $userDailyWin->setUserId($userId);
            $userDailyWin->setMultiplier(0);
            $userDailyWin->setClaimed(0);
            $userDailyWin->setStreak(0);
            $userDailyWin->setLastLogin($currentDate);

            $em->persist($userDailyWin);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So which $user do you expect to have injected?

Comment: @Cerad - User which is logged in (that is my target)

Comment: So consider searching for how to get the current logged in user.  Maybe take a look at Controller::getUser() as an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The user is not a symfony service and it will not get autowired.

Try with this interface:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface
```

Then you do:

```
$user=$tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Symfony 3.2, a new user resolver was introduced. It does not seem to allow the injection via constructor (I was also trying to make this work), but you should inject in your methods instead.

```
public function onKernelController(UserInterface $user , FilterControllerEvent $event) {
```

according to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but in controllers you can also just use:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

since Symfony 3.2, see [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers)