# Symfony bug with UserInterface and getToken

Tags: symfony

Helle there !

I'm currently working on a auth with JWT.
I'm with Symfony 5.3
I have an error when I want to test my login :

```
<!-- Cannot autowire argument $user of &quot;App\Controller\AuthController::getTokenUser()&quot;: it references interface &quot;Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface&quot; but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface? (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

I have installed security bundle and my user entity :

```
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
```

Can someone helps me ?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid using images in questions.  Consider updating the question and copy/pasting in the relevant portion of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have you written the line:

```
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
```

without previously creating the `use` statement?

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
```

It is a typical overlook when you are used to your IDE doing it for you, and at a particular moment it doesn't happen.

If this is the case, this also applies to `PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface`

Comment: Hello Thanks for you answer.

But I have : 

`namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface`

Comment: Check this question, it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47964557/17089665

Comment: I have always the error /:

Answer (score 0):

The error says there's an issue with your `AuthController::getTokenUser()` method, not with your `User` class. Could you post that method's signature?

My guess based on what you posted is that your method looks something like this:
`public function getTokenUser(UserInterface $user)...`

If you need the current `User` in that controller method, you should inject `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` and then call `$security->getUser()` like this:

```
public function getTokenUser (Security $security)
{
    $user = $security->getUser();
}
```